# SF story: aliens mistakenly leave human baby with intelligence "toy"?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

The aliens mistakenly leave an intelligence "cube" or toy with a human baby and later realize they miscategorized Earth and that no human should have that cube. They return shortly and take the cube back, and the baby, now hyperintelligent, in his crib rages, helpless to change the fact that it will now take him years--eight? ten? fifteen?--to control all of earth. Likely a short from 50s-70s.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mimsy_Were_the_Borogoves?

Comment: Mimsy Were the Borogoves is definitely not it.  Many toys, not one "cube".  Two children, not a baby.  The toys are left behind.  Many other minor discrepancies.

Answer (score 13):

**SF story: aliens mistakenly leave human baby with intelligence "toy"?**

["Teething Ring"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46243), short story by [James Causey](http://tellersofweirdtales.blogspot.com/2011/05/james-causey-1924-2003.html); first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, January 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58522+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v05n04_1953-01.Galaxy/Galaxy%20v05n04%20%281953-01.Galaxy%29#page/n31/mode/2up); reprinted in a number of anthologies, some of them [shown here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?46243); etext at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29625), audio at [LibriVox](https://librivox.org/short-science-fiction-collection-035/).

**The aliens mistakenly leave an intelligence "cube" or toy with a human baby**

> "I know just the thing," Porteous said happily. "Here." He dipped into the glittering litter on the tray and handed Harry Junior a translucent prism. "A neural distorter. We use it to train regressives on Rigel Two. It might be of assistance."
>
> Melinda eyed the thing doubtfully. Harry Junior was peering into the shifting crystal depths with a somewhat strained expression.
>
> "Speeds up the neural flow," explained the little man proudly. "Helps tap the unused eighty per cent. The pre-symptomatic memory is unaffected, due to automatic cerebral lapse in case of overload. I'm afraid it won't do much more than cube his present IQ, and an intelligent idiot is still an idiot, but—"

**and later realize they miscategorized Earth and that no human should have that cube. They return shortly and take the cube back,**

> "Major Nord, Galactic Security." The little man bowed. "You were visited early this morning by one Porteous." He spoke the name with a certain disgust. "He left a neural distorter here. Correct?"
>
> Melinda's nod was tremulous. Major Nord came quietly into the living room, shut the door behind him. "My apologies, madam, for the intrusion. Porteous mistook your world for a Class IV culture, instead of a Class VII. Here—" He handed her the crumpled dollar bill. "You may check the serial number. The distorter, please."

**and the baby, now hyperintelligent, in his crib rages, helpless to change the fact that it will now take him years--eight? ten? fifteen?--to control all of earth.**

> Harry Junior was sobbing bitterly into his pillow. He was sick with disappointment. Even the most favorable extrapolation showed it would take him nineteen years to become master of the world.
>
> An eternity. Nineteen years!

Comment: Galaxy. Bloody Galaxy. And here's me rummaging through Astounding Science Fiction.